# Ascending and descending sorting using BST insert method query

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

I want to insert a new object newPat as a binary node to the BST in descending order of urgency data field. I am doing the below code in ascending order. How can I change it to descending order?

BST class:

```
public void insertPatient(Patient newPat)
{
    BNode temp = new BNode(newPat);
    root = insert(root, temp);
}


protected BNode insert(BNode rt, BNode newNode)
{
    //attach newnode to correct subtree keeping ascending order and returns pointer to the node which it was called
    if(rt == null){
        rt = newNode; //last node becomes root           
    }else 
    {
        if((newNode.obj.getKey().compareTo(rt.obj.getKey()) < 0))
        {
            rt.left = insert (rt.left, newNode);
        } 
        else 
        {
            rt.right = insert (rt.right, newNode);
        }
    }
    return rt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In a Binary Search Tree(as per common understanding), `root` will not be minimum or maximum(unless your insertion order ensure or rotations are performed to manage the property. in such case, it will have worst case  time complexity)
2. If you always need the minimum or maximum, try looking into `Binomial Heap`

### Update based on author's clarification

As the existing code is inserting `lesser` values to `left` subtree and `bigger` values to the right subtree, changing the `<` to `>=` should solve your use case.

```java
    protected BNode insert(BNode parent, BNode newNode) {
        if (parent == null) {
            return newNode;
        }
        if (newNode.obj.getKey().compareTo(parent.obj.getKey()) >= 0) {
            parent.left = insert (parent.left, newNode);
        } else {
            parent.right = insert (parent.right, newNode);
        }
        return parent;
    }
```

With this new property of `descending`, ensure to update your search function also from `<` to `>=`. Else insert will work and search will fail to recognize the node.

### Suggestion

Alternatively, the insertion order can remain the same and retrieval logic can be changed to traverse the (`ascending`) tree from `right` to `left` to get the same behavior.

Keeping the existing code as it is for insertion (`<` comparison)

```java
    protected List<Patient> descendingInorder(BNode node, List<Patient> values) {
        if (node == null) {
            return values;
        }
        descendingInorder(node.right, values);
        values.add(node.obj);
        descendingInorder(node.left, values);
        return values;
    }
```

### Note

1. If the tree can contain, duplicates, then ensure to define the behavior for that.

Comment: thank you, you described this so well to me i appreciate a lot for explaining wish you an amazing day

Comment: Glad to be of help. Thank you too. I would encourage you to try out few different approaches before asking a question in SO. It will help you in long run. This is only a suggestion and not to discourage you from asking questions. Bye